# PHP producing loads of temporary files

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

My host provider (Bluehost) has disabled all my sites because of an error related to Piwigo or one of it's plugins.  This is their email response:

> Your account is deactivated because it is filling the servers hard
>   disks with temporary files. You need to check over your entire account
>   and make sure that you are A. Removing any temporary files that are
>   being created. B. You have disabled you scripts from creating files in
>   the /var/tmp directory.

The example they gave me was:

```
-rw-------  1 searchtheearth searchtheearth 106M Feb 16 09:49 magick-muzpwYvI
```

Bluehost took me down before I could continue to see anything.

I tried to deal with tech support but they insist it is not their job to troubleshoot
the scripts that they provide (Piwigo) and have not yet re-enabled my sites.
I told them I can not properly troubleshoot the site if it is not able to be accessed
and they said I can look at all my files and find the problem and only then once I 
can attest that there is no problem will they enable my account.

Frankly I am just looking for what causes the error

```
thrown in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 460
 [16-Feb-2014 12:21:42 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception      'ImagickException' with message 'unable to extend cache
```

and

```
 PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140211154425-  be740e47.jpg): Incorrect APP1 Exif    Identifier Code in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
```

So I have placed the error log below and anyone have any ideas as to what would be putting files in the `/var/tmp` directory and causing the errors below?

My error log is below for the server:

/public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/uploadify/error_log:

```
[11-Feb-2014 15:44:25 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140211154425-  be740e47.jpg): Incorrect APP1 Exif Identifier Code in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[13-Feb-2014 11:37:42 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140213113742-b6fb09db.jpg): Incorrect APP1 Exif Identifier Code in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:08 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165308-6d0d3b81.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x4B78, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:10 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165310-8d9c63a0.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x6170, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:11 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165311-bfedab06.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x693D, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:12 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165312-03fcfcf9.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x632E, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:13 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165313-85188689.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x57E3, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165314-6b4e44f0.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x5328, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:16 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165316-c465919f.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x3E9E, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:17 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165317-50abf12c.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x416D, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:19 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165319-ebf0f884.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x754E, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:20 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165320-3a023621.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x7B9D, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:22 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165322-834b0071.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x789E, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:23 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165323-1fd8c75c.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x4517, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:24 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165324-477282ab.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x7168, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:26 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165326-fd61f0e5.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x5E68, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:27 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165327-e4c0b6e3.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x6D32, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:28 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165328-5d93e8d6.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x5288, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:31 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165330-f3803539.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x641D, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:32 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165332-ad04e773.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x708F, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
[14-Feb-2014 16:53:34 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(20140214165334-f67793ed.jpg): Process tag(x0202=JPEGInterch): Illegal format code 0x920D, suppose BYTE in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 244
```

/public_html/searchtheearth/error_log:

```
    #5 {main}
    thrown in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 460
    [16-Feb-2014 12:21:42 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception    'ImagickException' with message 'unable to extend cache `/public_html/searchtheearth/upload/2014/02/15/20140215093344-cc4b26dc.jpg': No space left    on device @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/4102' in   /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php:460
    Stack trace:
    #0 /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php(460): Imagick-   >scaleimage(1536, 1152)
    #1 [internal function]: image_imagick->resize(792, 594)
    #2 /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php(93):   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
     #3 /public_html/searchtheearth/i.php(557): pwg_image->__call('resize', Array)
    #4 /public_html/searchtheearth/i.php(557): pwg_image->resize(792, 594)
    #5 {main}
  thrown in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line 460
    [16-Feb-2014 12:21:43 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception      'ImagickException' with message 'unable to extend cache `/public_html/searchtheearth/upload/2014/02/15/20140215093344-cc4b26dc.jpg': No space left    on device @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/4102' in    /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php:460
    Stack trace:
    #0 /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php(460): Imagick-  >scaleimage(1536, 1152)
    #1 [internal function]: image_imagick->resize(792, 594)
    #2 /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php(93):   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #3 /public_html/searchtheearth/i.php(557): pwg_image->__call('resize', Array)
    #4 /public_html/searchtheearth/i.php(557): pwg_image->resize(792, 594)
    #5 {main} thrown in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line     460
    [16-Feb-2014 12:21:44 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception  'ImagickException' with message 'unable to extend cache `/public_html/searchtheearth/upload/2014/02/15/20140215093344-cc4b26dc.jpg': No space left   on device @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/4102' in  /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php:460
    Stack trace:
    #0 /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php(460): Imagick-  >scaleimage(1536, 1152)
     #1 [internal function]: image_imagick->resize(792, 594)
    #2 /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php(93):   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #3 /public_html/searchtheearth/i.php(557): pwg_image->__call('resize', Array)
    #4 /public_html/searchtheearth/i.php(557): pwg_image->resize(792, 594)
    #5{main)  thrown in /public_html/searchtheearth/admin/include/image.class.php on line    460
    [16-Feb-2014 12:33:58 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

   /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/LocalFilesEditor/error_log:
   [12-Feb-2014 13:28:12 America/Denver] PHP Warning:     file_get_contents(../../plugins/adult_content/language/en_GB/plugin.lang.php): failed to   open stream: No such file or directory in   /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/LocalFilesEditor/show_default.php on line 41

    /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/oAuth/error_log:
    [11-Feb-2014 05:33:44 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in    /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/oAuth/auth.php on line 165
    [11-Feb-2014 13:13:23 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in    /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/oAuth/auth.php on line 165

    /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/error_log:
    [12-Feb-2014 10:29:23 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in    /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [12-Feb-2014 10:44:59 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in   /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
     [12-Feb-2014 10:44:59 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle()   in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line    83
    [12-Feb-2014 10:47:20 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in   /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [12-Feb-2014 10:47:20 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in   /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [12-Feb-2014 10:47:50 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in   /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [12-Feb-2014 10:56:45 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [12-Feb-2014 10:56:45 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in    /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [12-Feb-2014 10:57:00 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [12-Feb-2014 11:04:52 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [12-Feb-2014 11:04:52 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [12-Feb-2014 11:05:26 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [12-Feb-2014 11:05:31 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:26:58 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:26:58 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:29:10 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:29:35 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:30:20 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:30:20 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
    [14-Feb-2014 07:30:27 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:30:44 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:30:44 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:31:03 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 07:31:12 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 21:16:43 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 21:37:13 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 21:37:37 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 21:37:57 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
   [14-Feb-2014 21:38:18 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83
[   15-Feb-2014 07:23:41 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare drawcircle() in  /public_html/searchtheearth/plugins/EasyCaptcha/tictac/functions_tictac.inc.php on line 83

------------------------------------end of log---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Piwigo version:  2.6.1
PHP version: 5.4.24
MySQL version:  5.5.36
Piwigo URL: http://searchtheearth.com

Comment: "I can not properly troubleshoot the site if it is not able to be accessed and they said I can look at all my files and find the problem" -- Can you download your source from the server? Testing your code on localhost would be an ideal means to find the solution.

Comment: They're right, it's *not* their problem. [Ask the people that made this Piwigo app](http://piwigo.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Piwigo caches images, this is filling up your space.
How many images are on your space?

The exception you get is simply because you don't have any space left since it created so many images. You should find a way to disable image caching i.e. disabling imagemagick or commenting those lines out of Piwigo if it doesn't have a "turn off image caching" feature